# firefox bookmarks on mac os

Tags: firefox, bookmarklet

I am looking to change the `location` field (programmatically -> through code) of a firefox bookmark on a mac. Where are they stored. I have searched and I can not find the location.

Comment: See if this link helps any: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are stores in a places.sqlite database inside the profiles folder.